# VS CODE not showing Matplotlib images

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple script that reads and shows images in Matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.image as mpimg 


baseimg = '/home/ahmad/Downloads/mnist/trainingSample/img_0.jpg'
img = mpimg.imread(baseimg)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

It is working on Jupyter Notebook but when I run it in VS Code, it runs but does not show any image.[image] Is there some problem in my code or how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: try plt.show(block=False)

Comment: Still not working